# Do I need a transit visa for the UK if I have a valid US visa?

Tags: visas, transit

I am a South African passport holder with a valid USA visit visa. I am flying from South Africa to Dublin, Ireland, via London. Do I need a transit visa for the UK?

Comment: Airside transit: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/somewhere_else/no

Going through immigration transit: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/transit/somewhere_else/yes

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as long as you have a valid entry visa for Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA, you can transit airside in the UK without a transit visa as a south african.

source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/728210/UK_Visa_requirements_July_2018.pdf

Comment: If the final destination is Ireland, it won't be an airside transit.

Comment: I don't see why it won't be an airside transit. You can fly from London to Dublin.

Comment: As I understand it, because of the Common Travel Area, the flight from London to Dublin is "domestic", and therefore you have to go through UK immigration in London.  An airside transit visa is for cases when you wouldn't have to pass through UK immigration at all.